# Is there any way to Clear VSTS logs dynamically

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is there a way to clear VSTS logs dynamically from the Azure Devops Release once a condition say an exception is hit.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean to delete the release log when the release fails?

Comment: Yes, the release logs just for the failed task.